# Getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'" while scraping data from flipkart?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scape mobile data from Flipkart. Below is the code that I have written
[image]

Below is the actual code of the image:

```
home_page_link = "https://www.flipkart.com"
href = "/search?q=mobiles&as=on&as- show=on&otracker=AS_Query_TrendingAutoSuggest_1_0_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_Query_TrendingAutoSuggest_1_0_na_na_na&as-pos=1&as-type=TRENDING&suggestionId=mobiles&requestId=55feeb8d-8549-48a8-9325-1c0e8756151e&page=1"
url = home_page_link + href
for i in range(1, 101):
    print("page: ", i)

    page_response = requests.get(url)
    print(page_response)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')

#   cards = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': '_1UoZlX'})

#   for card in cards:
#       name = card.find("div", attrs={'class': '_3wU53n'})
#       price = card.find('div', attrs={'class': '_1vC4OE'})
#       print(name.text, price.text)
    

    next_link = soup.find("a",text = "Next")

    print(type(next_link))

    link = next_link.get("href")
    home_page_link = "https://www.flipkart.com"
    next_page_link = home_page_link + link
    url = next_page_link
```

I got nonetype object at page 29:
[image]

After executing the same code again:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change the page in flipkart for getting all the record.

you can change page easily by changing the last character in the link. you just have to change the page value in the link.

For getting the all the page try this :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
home_page_link = "https://www.flipkart.com"
href = "/search?q=mobiles&as=on&as- show=on&otracker=AS_Query_TrendingAutoSuggest_1_0_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_Query_TrendingAutoSuggest_1_0_na_na_na&as-pos=1&as-type=TRENDING&suggestionId=mobiles&requestId=55feeb8d-8549-48a8-9325-1c0e8756151e&page="       # remove last character which show page number.
url = home_page_link + href
print(url)
for i in range(1, 101):
    print("page: ", i)
    new_url = url + str(i)       # add page number in the link every time value of `i` change, also page is increment.
    page_response = requests.get(new_url)
    print(page_response)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Great! It's working. Thanks @Bhargav Desai. But could you please help me understand why the (text = "Next") thing is not working i.e. my approach? Even that is also a way to get the next page link. Where my code is facing the issue?